# Row number of the last non-empty row

Tags: excel, powershell

How can I determine the row number of the *last* non-empty row using Powershell?

I know that I can evaluate if a row is empty using the following statement:

```
$Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountA($outputWorksheet.Range("1:1"))
```

Is there are better than to iterate through all rows that are marked by Excel as used (i.e., `$outputWorksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count`)?

Comment: `$LastRowUsed = $outputWorksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count` will give you the last row used by excel. Simply putting `$LastRowUsed + 1` will give you the first non-empty row available. Is this what you are looking for?
IMO, it is `$LastRowUsed + 1` row where you will start inserting new data.

Comment: In theory yes, but `UsedRange.Rows.Count` is in some cases far too great. In case of a document I encountered I got 520 instead of 55.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As UsedRange.Count reports the maximum number of lines that were *ever* used in a Worksheet, I just brute force through all rows.
Here is the code I use:

```
#Determine the last empty row - brute force.
For ($i = $outputWorksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count; $i -gt 1; $i--) {
   if (!$Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountA($outputWorksheet.Range("$($i):$($i)")) -eq 0) {
       $lastRow = "A$($i + 1)"
       Break;
   }
}
```